# Creating a IPv4 packet header in python

Tags: python, ipv4

For my larger project i need to start with creating a IPv4 network packet ( for simulation )

for the same I need to write a function that creates a header out of the passed data which has the source ip , dest ip and all the necessary fields

```
def convertIpv4( data ):
     pass
```

For this I need you to guide me in the right direction.

Firstly I need to store the IP in 32 bits so for that if I have a string "192.168.2.1" what is the most efficient way to convert it into bytes and that too a size of 32 ??

Also if I create first a normal class with stuff like version = 4 and sourceip and dest ip then is there a way to convert it directly into a byte array with the position of objects just like the following header [image: IPHeader]

Please tell how should i proceed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [PyIP](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyip/) module.

Answer (score 1):

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) can create IP headers easily.
[Here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#starting-scapy) they have an example on creating IP header.